# Zend Framework 2 TableGateway wrong field mapping

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

Trying to adapt the ZF2 [skeleton application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html), I'm having trouble with the fields retrieved in the resultSet.
My table 'project' contains four fields: id, title, shortTitle, year.
I'm using the typical fetchAll function:

```
public function fetchAll() {
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
```

The Project class reflects the four fields

```
class Project {
    public $id;
    public $title;
    public $shortTitle;
    public $year;

  public function exchangeArray($data) {
      $this->id = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
      $this->title = (!empty($data['title'])) ? $data['title'] : null;
      $this->shortTitle = (!empty($data['shortTitle'])) ? $data['shortTitle'] : null;
      $this->year = (!empty($data['year'])) ? $data['year'] : null;
  }
}
```

The table gateway factory in Module.php is as described by the tutorial:

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Project\Model\ProjectTable' => function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProjectTableGateway');
                    $table = new ProjectTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'ProjectTableGateway' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Project());
                    return new TableGateway('project', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
```

The query passed to the database is correct and gives correct results:

```
SELECT `project`.* FROM `project`
```

$resultSet looks like it's getting the right prototype and the correct number of rows, but it does not match the column names properly. print_r($resultSet->current()); gives:

```
Project\Model\Project Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => Some title 1 
      [shortTitle] => [year] => )
```

While print_r($data); in exchangeArray function gives:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Some title 1 [project] => 2012 )
```

It seems the object gets only the first two fields right, and then creates a field [project] with the value of the last column available within the result.

I must have made a stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't figure out where.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this is what is causing your problem but since i have never seen it used like this, could you try and change !empty() to what the official documentation suggests $this->id     = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried, to no avail, sadly. Note that the version of the "official documentation' I'm using was proposing !empty(), not isset(): see http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Comment: Yes you are right. Did not notice that change from 2.1. Does it still return project with year?

Comment: No change, unfortunately.

Comment: could you try a raw query like this?                        $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
//create query                                              $resultSet = $adapter->query("SELECT project.* FROM project",array());                                              //convert object to Array
$rowData=$resultSet->toArray();
return $rowData;                                                  Just to see if you are still getting the same results?

Comment: Yes, it gives exactly the same results:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => A long title [project] => 2014 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => test 2 full title [project] => 2014 ) )

Comment: Note that if I run the query: SELECT id, shortTitle from project, I get the results:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [shortTitle] => A short title ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [shortTitle] => test 2 ) )

If I then add another field to the query, such as SELECT id, shortTitle, year from project, I now get:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [shortTitle] => A short title [project] => 2014 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [shortTitle] => test 2 [project] => 2014 ) )<

This is all very weird...

Comment: Longshot...rename the field from year to some_name. In case year is a reserved word

Comment: That was one of my first thoughts -- that and TableGateway not liking camelcase field names -- so I already tried this. Needless to say, it didn't help... Let me try and drop the database and create it again, just to make sure there's not something fishy in there.

Comment: I dropped the table and created it again, same problem. Bummer. Since no one else seems to have the same problem, it must be something to do with the install. I did a manual install of the skeleton app on GitHub, then followed the tutorial steps as exactly as I could, but for the name of the table and columns. Any other idea?

Comment: This is all very confusing. Nevertheless if you run a direct query on the db and not from zend are the results correct?

Comment: I would have expected `print_r($resultSet->current());` to be returning a `Project` object, rather than an `Array`. `ResultSet` only returns an array if the prototype isn't an `ArrayObject` or any class with an `exchangeArray` method so there would seem to be an issue there. I'd maybe start by looking at the TableGateway factory you set up to be sure you're telling it to use your `Project` model class as prototype.

Comment: Crisp -- you're right, I pasted the wrong debut trace. print_r($resultset->current()) does return a Project object with the correct structure. However, the $data passed to exchangeArray contains: Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Some title 1 [project] => 2012 ). This seems to show that there is an issue with TableGateway somewhere.

Comment: @phme - you mean to say that the result of `public function exchangeArray($data) { print_r($data); exit(); [....]  }` gives you the array with `[project]` key and the `[shortTitle]` & `[year]` are missing. Please confirm again.

Comment: @kunal-dethe: yes, this is correct. I edited again the question to make that clearer.

Comment: One of the reason to have such a scenario is when the database table itself has a field by the name `project`. If that's not the case then I am also eager to know the solution.

Comment: ok, I retried with exactly the same structure as shown in the tutorial for 2.3, with the Album model (and corresponding MySQL table) not changing anything, just copying and pasting code. I have the same problem. There must be an issue with the install. Can anyone confirm the tutorial works with ZF 2.3 as is?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your TableGateway factory in the Module.php - It should be similar to this -

Will need the `use ...` statements too.

```
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use [.....]\Model\Product;          //Add the Module Name here
use [.....]\Model\ProductTable;     //Add the Module Name here

'Project\Model\ProjectTable' => function($sm) { //Change Module name accordingly.
    $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProjectTableGateway');
    $table = new ProjectTable($tableGateway);
    return $table;
},
'ProjectTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Project());
    return new TableGateway('project', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype); 
    //Change the the tablename accordingly.
},
```

Then add the result of `print_r($resultSet->current());` in your question description.

Comment: Thanks Kunal, I pasted my factory definition, which is exactly matching yours, and corrected results of the print_r you suggested.